# Ubuntu 12.10 error in select and install software

Tags: installation, 12.10

I keep having this error msg and I dont know what is wrong:

> select and install software
>   installation step failed  an installation step failed. 
>   you can try to run the faling item again from the menu,
>   or skip it and choose something else. the failing step is: select and
>   install software

And then the main menu appears what should I click or do to go the next step which is GRUB boot loader?

Answer (score 1):

For whatever it's worth, I ran into this same issue installing Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS (downloaded 8/25/2013). I simply skipped the "Select and Install Software" step and everything seems fine so far. As best as I can tell that step is only there for convenience and isn't actually required for installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Correction: I did have an issue being able to find anything in aptitude because the /etc/apt/sources.list was empty. So, I went to this handy apt sources list generator: http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/, and added all sources but the third party sources. Then, I commented out everything that was in /etc/apt/sources.list and pasted in everything from that generator. Here is the sources list I used: http://pastebin.com/KzhpDE5K. As for getting that list to your server, you may have to resort to fancy work with netcat.

Comment: And I had to do some nonsense with apt keys to get apt-get update to work. I don't remember what I did, but just a heads up you may have issues.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, I had such message not with my 12.10 - is this concerning synaptic ?

have you tried simply:

sudo apt-get install --reinstall synaptic

?

be more specific: is this - what you described - happening during installation of
ubuntu ? or simply as user logged in at desktop ?

Comment: it's while installing the software for a server (not virtual), and no I didn't use synaptic , I'm a new to ubuntu it's my first day